# Javascript: How to wait for eval-function?

Tags: javascript, async-await, eval

I am working on a project that paints Objects from Blockly Code Blocks. Therefore a code string is generated that is evaluated in the function below. In the code run with the eval function, all created objects are stored in an array (objects). My problem is that the code is not completely evaluated before alert(objects.length) can work with the updated objects array (so it alerts zero as I have reset the array before). So the alert should wait for the eval function. Can you help me how to solve this problem?

```
function paintFromCode() {
   slideTo('konva_box');
   setTimeout(function(){
       deleteObjects();
       let code = Blockly.JavaScript.workspaceToCode(workspace);
       try {
          code = "let t = 0;" + code;
          eval(code);
       } catch (e) {
          alert(e);
       }
       layer.add(pospanel);
       alert(objects.length);
   }, 1000);
}
```

Part of the function where the code is created:

```
let code = "setTimeout( function() {" +
    "objects['" + text_identifier.toUpperCase() + "'] = new Konva.Circle({x: 50, y: 100, radius: 50, fill: '#00ff00'});" +
    "layer.add(objects['" + text_identifier.toUpperCase() + "']);" +
    "layer.draw();" +
    "}, speed * t);" + 
    "t = t + 1;";
return code;
```

Comment: `eval(code)` does wait for the code to complete. Could there be async function calls in `code`?

Comment: Actually that's possible. It's the Konva Framework. How can I get around this?

Comment: Maybe ths solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56187117/await-is-only-valid-in-async-function-eval-in-async) will work for you?

Comment: Please post the value of `code`

Comment: @Barmar I tried that before I posted my question here. It didn't work for me so far.

Comment: @Bergi I don't think that will help you because I just call functions from the Konkav framework.

Comment: @Jue But these matter for your question. The exact code might not, but which functions do you call and how are they asynchronous? Can you link the docs of that framework?

Comment: @Bergi [Konva-Framework](https://konvajs.org/api/Konva.html)

Comment: If you do not have control over what is being executed you are sort of out of luck. If you can alter logic that you are executing that would be a better solution and you can have more options.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have written the code above, it seems you control `layer`. Running the code block has a call to `layer.draw()` at the end. You can redefine draw to call your `alert` statement.

```
// store original draw function
const orginalDraw = layer.draw;
layer.draw = function() {
   originalDraw();
   alert('draw has just been called');
}
try {
  code = "let t = 0;" + code;
  eval(code);
} catch (e) { alert(e); }
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** My initial response was unnecessarily complex...  With the assumption that the setTimeout is occurring within the Blockly Code Blocks returned code string, suggest intercepting the `setTimeout` function, and inserting the post-timeout processing there.  (Another alternative is to search and replace entries of setTimeout within the Blockly Code Blocks code string, replacing with a similar custom setTimeout function that performs post-timeout processing also.)

```js
// Simulate ==> let code = Blockly.JavaScript.workspaceToCode(workspace);
// with an embedded setTimeout in the code to be eval-ed.
let code = `
  setTimeout( () => alert('Blocky!'), 2000);
`;

// Define the custom function to run once the setTimeout is complete.
var a = 0;
function postTimeout( x ) {
  console.log( a );
  a = x;
  console.log( a );
  alert( a );
}

// Finally, execute the "Blocky" code. But first, intercept the setTimeout
// function and afterwards reset it.  Alternatively, one can search and
// replace 'setTimeout(' in the Blocky code, replacing with similar 
// intercepting function.
const stf = setTimeout;
setTimeout = function(f,ms) {
  return stf( () => { f(); postTimeout( 42 ) }, ms)
};
  
eval( code );

setTimeout = stf;
```

Upon running this snippet, in 2 seconds the `alert('Blocky!')` will fire representing the Blocky code with the setTimeout function, and then immediately afterwards, the custom `postTimeout` function will fire which simulates the

```
layer.add(pospanel);
alert(objects.length);
```

in the question.

I have included `var a` as  a test of reaching beyond the scope of the "Blocky" javascript within the `code` variable...

Answer (score 0):

> i had same problem and here is how i handled it

```
try { 
       eval("(async () => {"+code+"})()");

        }
catch (e) {
                       alert(e);
                          }
```

and code was splitted in myArr1 by function and after each function i added

```
   let wait='); await this.waitfunction(500);';
                         for (var i=0; i<myArr1.length-1;i++){

                        let tex=
                      myArr1[i].concat(wait);
                  b[i]=tex;
                  

                  }
```

here is my waitfunction():

```
waitfunction(ms){

return new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(()=>resolve(''),ms)
   });
}
```

i know that was long but it works