# Why does await eval('`${await foo("xxx")}`') throw an error

Tags: javascript, node.js

Before I get flamed for using eval()... YES, I know eval === evil and from the devil and should never be used. That is NOT the question here. Believe it or not, I actually have a valid, real life case where it makes perfect sense to use eval, as a matter of fact, there is no other way to achieve the result I require.

Below is a code snippet with 4 cases. The first three works exactly as expected. The first two calls an async function in a template literal. The 3rd and 4th stores the template literal as a string and then eval the string. In the case (no 3) where await is not used, as expected the promise is returned. The problem is however case 4. It throws an error and for the life of me, I can't figure out why, or how to get around it.

I'm hoping someone smarter than me can either come up with a solution so that case 4 can still be evaluated without throwing an error (first prize) or explain why it doesn't work/can't be done.

```js
async function foo(str) {
    return str.toUpperCase();
}

async function bar() {
    const str1 = `${foo("xxx")}`;

    console.log("STR1:", str1);
    // Output: STR1: [object Promise]

    const str2 = `${await foo("xxx")}`;

    console.log("STR2:", str2);
    // Output: STR2: XXX

    const str3 = '`${foo("xxx")}`';

    console.log("STR3:", await eval(str3));
    //Output STR3: [object Promise]

    const str4 = '`${await foo("xxx")}`';

    console.log("STR4:", await eval(str4));
    // undefined:1
    // `${await foo("xxx")}`
    //    ^^^^^^
    // Output: SyntaxError: Missing } in template expression
}

bar();
```

Comment: Because you're having extra await in the str4, when the `eval` evaluates the `str4`, the code becomes `await await foo('xxx')` which results in an error

Comment: You can have as many awaits as you want, it doesn't matter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [await is only valid in async function - eval in async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56187117/await-is-only-valid-in-async-function-eval-in-async)

Comment: also, note that `await eval(...)` doesn't make sense: `eval` itself does not return a promise, so you'd have to make the string you pass to eval _build_ a promise. I.e. ```await eval(`new Promise(resolve => resolve(...))`)``` _would_ make sense. Although as you of course mentioned, not a _lot_ of sense because there is almost guaranteed no reason for eval here, or anywhere else, in a modern codebase =)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Actually await eval(...) makes perfect sense in this case because the template literal being evaluated makes use of an async function that does return a promise. Therefore you will not be able to evaluate the template literal if you do not "await" the eval.

As for your assumption "here is almost guaranteed no reason for eval here, or anywhere else, in a modern codebase", it is flawed. I've built an whole API abstraction layer that has been running in production for well over 12 months, that are used by a number of South Africa's biggest retailers. ....

Comment: ... The sole purpose of this API is to sit between the retailer and other API providers and to "translate" the API requests from the retailer into a request that the API provider understand and to then "translate" the response from the provider to a standard format that the retailer understands. We interface with a large number of API providers. I can set up this interface between the retailer and the provider typically under an hour without writing a line of code, and with the whole configuration sitting in a database. All of this relies heavily on being able to use eval.

Comment: That doesn't sound like it needs eval anywhere, that sounds like you just need to have the same code running on both ends and do some boring JSON back and forth. And if you're running all these retailers without CSP headers that turns off unsafe-eval, that's... a highly questionable security policy. Nothing is highly reliant on  eval, it's reliant on what eval _effects_, which can always be effected in a more secure way. ("I didn't ask for a lecture on eval": I know, but you're still getting one. It's that big of a security risk).

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans You are of course 100% correct in that using Eval to interpret data received from an external source is a pretty dumb idea. However, in this case it is not used to interpret the data received by the API, but rather to take that data and "inject" it into templates. Because of the way it is used, receiving JSON data such as for example { "number": "${Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER}" } simply gives an "Unexpected token S in JSON at position..." error. Because of eval, it is possible for me to take a JSON request that comes from an internal system, and to "translate" it into ...

Comment: ... a JSON request format that is expected by an external 3rd party API. In the same way we can then take the response that comes from this 3rd party, and "translate" this message back into the JSON response expected by the internal system. Doing this allows us to very easily build standard API interfaces for our clients for a diverse set of 3rd party APIs and all of this can be sone simply by setting up the translation templates in a DB, and not write a line of code.

Comment: If you get an `Unexpected token S in JSON at position` or the like, then your JSON is malformed, and that's definitely something to look at. Also, what you describe is exactly what you describe: templating. Do that server side and you won't need `eval`: just make clients load `<script src="yourserver/theirfile.js?id=clientid">` and have the server do that value injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way of making it work, basically by separating the awaiting of the promise from the construction of the string (kind of), using [tagged templates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#tagged_templates) is described below:

```js
async function foo(str) {
    return str.toUpperCase();
}

async function asyncFooTmpl(strings, asyncExpr) {
  return `${strings[0]}${await asyncExpr}${strings[1]}`;
}

async function bar() {
    const str1 = `${foo("xxx")}`;

    console.log("STR1:", str1);
    // Output: STR1: [object Promise]

    const str2 = `${await foo("xxx")}`;

    console.log("STR2:", str2);
    // Output: STR2: XXX

    const str3 = '`${foo("xxx")}`';

    console.log("STR3:", await eval(str3));
    //Output STR3: [object Promise]

    const str4 = 'asyncFooTmpl`${foo("xxx")}`';

    console.log("STR4:", await eval(str4));
    //Output STR4: XXX
}

bar();
```

This transfers the ownership of awaiting the promise from `bar` to `asyncFooTmpl`, allowing the string to be produced.

That said, it would require you to write functions for every template you have, or create a function that makes dealing with tagged templates more manageable.

Since you accepted this, and wrote your own answer combining my comment, I created [a fiddle of a somewhat more improved example](https://jsfiddle.net/mikemccaughan/or4xwsku/1/) if you're curious.

Comment: Thanks for an interesting approach. Unfortunately having "to write functions for every template you have" sort of defeats the purpose of using eval in the first place. The idea behind being able to evaluate a template, is that you can dynamically create/change templates.

Comment: I expect there's some way of "genericizing" the template function such that you can write one function that does it; I just don't have the time right now to dig into it. Something like `async function resolveTemplate(strings, ...maybePromises) { const final = []; for (let i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) { final.push(strings[i]); final.push(Object.prototype.toString.call(maybePromises[i]).includes('Promise') ? await maybePromises[i] : maybePromises[i]); } return final.join(''); }` and then use `resolveTemplate` instead of `asyncFooTmpl`. Haven't tested that, of course, but might get you going.

Comment: Thanks Mate. You humbled me. Even though you did not test your code, it worked "out of the box". Damn impressive!

To be honest, while I understand how it works, there are some things that I still do not fully grasp. I still don't understand how resolveTemplate`foo("xxx")` actually calls a function and how the strings and maybePromises are "automatically" populated.

Comment: I accepted Heretic Monkey's answer because it was ultimately the solution that worked. I did however also post an answer which contains a full working example for those that are interested.

Comment: I'm just good at guessing :). If you look at the page linked to in my answer, it goes over how tagged templates work. Perhaps not to the detail you want, but the other side of the coin is [the spec itself](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-expressions.html#sec-template-literals) which goes into mind-numbing detail.  Maybe I'll write something up on my blog at some point ‍♂️.

Answer (score 1):

It's not related to `eval` directly. You just can't use `await` outside of `async` function.

This will result in the same error:

```js
const x = `${await Promise.resolve()}`
```

Wrapping the call in async IIFE solves the issue:

```js
async function foo(str) {
  return str.toUpperCase();
}

async function bar() {
  const x = '`${(async () => await foo("xxx"))()}`'
  eval(x)
}

bar();
```

Proof that `await` can't be used in `eval` in `async` function, because `eval` isn't that simple

```js
async function foo(str) {
  return str.toUpperCase();
}

async function bar() {
  try {
    const x = ' await foo("xxx")`'
    eval(x)
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
  }
}

bar();
```

Comment: You seem to have stopped mid-sentence... And while that gets rid of the error, it doesn't produce the desired result. (use `console.log(eval(x))` and it will show `[object Promise]`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, but the reason the code you use to demonstrate why it fails is flawed in that you are trying to call await outside of an async function, as you state. My sample code does not. Everything is wrapped in an async function. As a matter of fact, your "fix" would work perfectly fine without "wrapping the code". In other words, the below code will work perfectly fine too.  (See STR3 in my sample code)

async function foo(str) {
  return str.toUpperCase();
}

async function bar() {
  const x = '`${await foo("xxx")}`'
  eval(x)
}

bar();

Comment: `eval` probably has its own execution context that doesn't inherit the `async` attribute

Comment: Try running `eval('await foo()')` inside your `bar` function. It will result in an error

Comment: @Gerhardvr updated the question with the proof

Answer (score 1):

I've tried many approaches and while I often came close to a solution, it never quite worked. The solution proposed by Heretic Monkey worked like a charm. I literally copied his code for "genericizing" the template function and it worked. Did not need to change a thing.

In case someone else is looking for a solution such as this, I'm posting the full example I put together to prove to myself that it works. The example is a bit long but I wanted to show a practical, real world use of the solution to make it easier of others to understand.

```js
async function foo(str) {
    await sleep(2000);
    console.log(`foo caled with ${str}`);
    return str.toUpperCase();
}

function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function resolveTemplate(strings, ...maybePromises) {
    const final = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
        final.push(strings[i]);
        final.push(Object.prototype.toString.call(maybePromises[i]).includes("Promise") ? await maybePromises[i] : maybePromises[i]);
    }
    return final.join("");
}

const person = { firstName: "Joe", lastName: "Blogs", Age: 23 };

async function bar() {
    let str = 'resolveTemplate`{ "name": "${foo(person.firstName.concat(" ",person.lastName))}", "age": ${person.Age}, "sex": "${foo("male")}" }`';

    console.log("STR4:", await eval(str));
    //Output STR4: { "name": "JOE BLOGS", "age": 23, "sex": "MALE" }
}

bar();

console.log("Done");
```